# VBA: filter pivot table according to previously defined variable

Tags: vba, excel, pivot

I have the following situation: need an VBA formula which filters a raw data sheet (HISTORICALS) for the two newest dates (already done). Then, the respective pivot (called PivotTable1 located in PIVOT sheet) should be filtered on these two dates. The respective column where the dates are located is called "ipg:date". Here is my code:

```
Sub Select_Last_Two_Days()

' select the PIVOT worksheet

With Worksheets("PIVOT")    
' select two highest dates
    Highest_Max = Format(WorksheetFunction.Large(Worksheets("HISTORICALS").Range("A:A"), 1), "Short Date")
    Second_Highest_Max = Format(WorksheetFunction.Large(.Range("A:A"), WorksheetFunction.CountIf(.Range("A:A"), WorksheetFunction.Max(.Range("A:A"))) + 1), "Short Date")
    Debug.Print Highest_Max, Second_Highest_Max

    ' filter pivot table for two highest dates
    Worksheets("PIVOT").PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("ipg:date"). _
        ClearAllFilters
    Worksheets("PIVOT").PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("ipg:date"). _
        PivotFilters.Add Type:=xlValueEquals, Value1:=Highest_Max, Value2:=Second_Highest_Max
End With

End Sub
```

The error I receive is:

> Unable to get the Large property of the WorksheetFunction class

I assume that `xlValueEquals` is not the right way to filter on my previously defined variables, but cannot find another filtering command which works.

Can someone direct me into the right direction?

Comment: another option would be that I extract the filter from Highest and Second Highest Max to some cells in the PIVOT sheet and then filtering the pivot date column based on the values in these cells. Trying that now..

Answer (score 0):

I can't say if this is the issue for sure, but my suspicion is that you are unable to filter your pivot using 'Highest_Max' because it is a string representation of a date, and not a true `Date` (check your locals window and you should see it there). The `Format` function will return a formatted string, but if the pivot table recognizes these values as true dates, it won't know what you mean when you pass it a string.

For what it is worth, you would likely be better off writing a function to return the two most recent dates (their value, not their string representation). For me at least, the use of `Application.WorksheetFunction` tends to be a code smell.

You'll also want to make sure you **declare your variables**. You can force declaration by adding `Option Explicit` to the top of your module. This will force a compile-time error for undeclared variables (I can't tell you how many times this will squash an otherwise time sucking bug).

**EDIT:** Completely missed that your error is because of the `WorksheetFunction`. This seems to be the line causing the issue:

```
Second_Highest_Max = Format(WorksheetFunction.Large(.Range("A:A"), WorksheetFunction.CountIf(.Range("A:A"), WorksheetFunction.Max(.Range("A:A"))) + 1), "Short Date")
```

Note that `.Range("")` is not fully qualified (I assume you intended to use a `With` block, but that is missing from your code). This means that the variable being passed to the `array` argument of the `WorksheetFunction.Large` function will not be an array, and in turn you'll see the function return an error.

Comment: But why would the second variable (Second_Highest_Max) cause an error? The syntax is basically the same compared to Highest_Max, only that a COUNTIF and MAX function.

Comment: Did you read my edit? The syntax is **almost** the same except for a very important thing that you are missing entirely. I explained it in my answer.